# How to fetch specific variable list using Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have `List<Person>` object `obj` containing variables like 'Name', 'Surname', etc.

How can I fetch just `List` of all Names using lambda expression only? (i.e x->x...)

Comment: Use `Select(x => x.Name)`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: foreach (string nameItem in list.FindAll(f => f.Name == "SomeName"))
{
    //do sth
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var x = obj.Select(x => x.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
//init list

var names = persons.Select(x=>x.Name);
```